# WCF ServiceRoute and Tcp

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF application hosted in IIS in which i use WsHttpBinding, with aspnetCompatibility since i want to use RouteTable functionality to route many calls to a single service.

every thing worked as expected, no problems here.

Then i added a tcp endpoint to the service(using its original url), and called the service using client, everything worked here, without a problem.

Then i modified the client url with routed url, and called the method using tcp endpoint, i got a socket error, which is what i expected.

But then i ran the wsHttp client with the routed url (which worked), and ran the tcp client with the routed url (which surprisingly worked)

Are tcp requests and http requests being routed through the same pipeline ?

Comment: Have you enabled the WCF Non-HTTP Activation on your machine / server and made sure the net.tcp bindings are registered on your website and application?

Comment: Yes all that is configured, and i can even call the net.tcp endpoint after i call the http one

Comment: my IIS version is 7.5 on Windows Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, the System.Web.Routing scenario is only supported for HTTP-based endpoints, since the *netTcpBinding* really doesn't use URLs in the same way.

--larsw

Comment: Is there any mechanism available to achieve such functionality -Routing- for net.tcp transport?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Microsoft's documentation on ServiceRoute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.activation.serviceroute(v=vs.110).aspx), it is **only** designed to **support extension-less base addresses over HTTP transport**.